# Stuck at NSIS script

Tags: nsis

I've problem understanding NSIS script which I got from extracting with 7zip from some installer. I've several questions:

1. Does `.onInit` function executes before anything?
2. what is meaning of `System::Call "*  (&t256) p  .r5  "` call? as I know from the documentation is creates new structure but what is `&t256` ?
3. As I know r0-r10 are registers, can I get value of r0 if r0 is pointer to some string, I need string, not pointer itself. `Messagebox MB_OK "$r0"` prints pointers
4. There is calls like `*$1(&t255 .r0)` I want to get value of $1.

Thank you

Comment: Looking at decompiled scripts is not the best way to learn NSIS.

Answer (score 0):

- Yes, `.onInit` is the first part of a .NSI that is executed. (Internally it will read `InstallDirRegKey` as the first action before calling `.onInit`)
- `t` is a string type, the same as `TCHAR` in C/C++. `*(&t256)p.r5` is a buffer of 256 characters, enough to hold a filename. It allocates memory and stores the address in `$5`.
- `r0` is the system plug-in register syntax, it is the same as `$0` in NSIS code, not `$R0`, that is a different register!
- If `$1` contains the address of a string in memory, `*$1(&t255 .r0)` will extract/place the first 255 characters of the string in `$0`.